# SSIS - How to access resultset data in script task that is contained in Foreach loop container?

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I've two nested foreach loop containers.  Each are looping on different resultsets.  I've a script task, within the inner foreach loop container, in which I need to be able to acccess values of current row of both the loops.  One way of doing it is using variable mappings on both the loops, but is there a way to access current row from within the script?  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access variables mapped in loop containers in script task via `Variables` property of the `Dts` object if you add this variables to `ReadOnlyVariables` or `ReadWriteVariables` lists in the Script Task Editor.

Map current row of each loop to variable and then access this variables in script task. Isn't this enough?

Example:

```
string fileName = (string) Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value;
```

You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx

Update:
You can map whole row to variable at once. Use `Object` as variable type and set Index = `-1` in Variable mappings in Foreach loop.You should receive enumerator, which type is related to enumerated collection.

Comment: Piotr, Thank you.  I'm aware of this method (variable mapping), but i was wondering if there was any other way without creating and mapping so many variables (of course depends on # of columns in the dataset).